# Is the definite article used before a year?

Tags: artículos, tiempo

In Spanish, is it better to say:
*Desde 2013* or *Desde el 2013*?
Similarly:
*En 2000* or *En el 2000*?

I understand Spanish often uses the definite article in the case of an implied noun (like *a las 3:00* meaning *a las 3:00 horas*), and to me the word *año* is implied here, but given my experience, I'm uncertain here. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/articulo-delante-de-los-anos/), which quotes the DPD, both are correct:

> Cuando se cita el año 2000 y los sucesivos, es válido tanto emplear el artículo delante como prescindir de él: *del 2020* o *de 2020*.
>
> No obstante, respecto a la expresión de los años, el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas indica que hay que tener en cuenta lo siguiente:
>
> 1. Desde el año 1 (y los anteriores a Cristo) hasta el año 1100, es más frecuente el empleo del artículo *el* y, por tanto, de la forma contraída de la preposición y el artículo, *del*: «Los árabes llegaron a España en el 711» o «El 14 de marzo del 413 a. C. hubo un terremoto en Asia Menor».
> 2. Del año 1100 hasta 1999, la omisión del artículo que evita la cacofonía /del-mil/ es mayoritaria: «27 de febrero de 1995» o «En 1783».
> 3. A partir del 2000, la tendencia mayoritaria es usar de nuevo el artículo *el* y, por consiguiente, la contracción *del* en la escritura de los años: «Cinco videojuegos esperados por los que se ansía la llegada del 2020» o «Las conclusiones del Consejo Asesor se harán públicas el 18 de enero del 2021», pero también se considera válido prescindir de él: «El precio de la vivienda crecerá un 9 % en 2020» y «En marzo de 2015 el Congreso de los Diputados aprobó la ley».
>
> Específicamente, en la datación de cartas y documentos, estas diferencias no han sido tan acusadas y el uso sin artículo ha tendido a mantenerse. En cualquier caso, ninguna de las dos opciones se considera incorrecta.

As a legal and financial translator, my recommendation is that the definite article be avoided at all times, because, though correct, it makes time phrases unnecessarily heavy.

Comment: Maybe you could give some examples with the OP's actual questions.